# How to make instance with same name class in java

Tags: java

I want to create an instance of class `B` that isn't a part of `A`'s inner class.

How can I achieve this? I'd like the class name to remain the same for both `B` classes.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.show();
    }
}

class A {
    class B {
        public void show() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        B b = new B();
        b.show();
    }
}

class B {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("hellohello");
    }
}
```

Comment: So _inside_ A you want to create an instance of the 'outer' class B?

Answer (score 4):

Use full qualified name of class B, i.e. `com.mypackage.mysubpackage.B` for outer `B` and `com.mypackage.mysubpackage.A.B` for inner B.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fully-qualified name of `B` to always refer to it: `packageName.B`.

This *won't* work if the class is in the unnamed (default) package (i.e. if there is no `package` declaration on top of its `.java` file). This is yet another reason not to use the unnamed package at all (i.e. all your classes should be in a named package).

Answer (score 2):

Use the complete identifier of the class you want to create an instance of (no `import` statement).

```
yourPackage.B variable = new yourPackage.B();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your main method with the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a = new A();
    a.show();
    //For Outer Class
    B bOuter =new B();
    bOuter.show();

    //For Inner Class
    A.B bInner=new A().new B();
    bInner.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use complete qualified name to keep away from conflict among same classes name.
E.g. `packageName.A.B` and `packageName.B`